# SSRS multiple value parameter - blank value resets parameter

Tags: reporting-services, parameters

I have a report with a multi-value parameter which allows for a blank value to be selected because the table which the report gets its data from has some blank values which need to be included.

Within VS this works perfectly fine.

On the actual report server, however, the parameter just resets (all values become unchecked) when I hit "Show report" with the blank value checked. It's fine when the blank value is unchecked.

Comment: What browser are you using?

Comment: if I understand you problem correct. Your report with blank checkbox are checked as default when run on VS but when upload to report server it's uncheck by default right ?

Comment: @WEI_DBA Chrome

Comment: @ChanomFirst No not exactly. Both in VS and in the browser, all values were unchecked by default but the report just couldn't be executed with the blank value checked in the browser.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I still have no idea, why exactly the problem occurred but deleting and re-uploading the report to the server solved it.